# I am trying to use boost library to load c++ dll to python in VS2013 but getting error : "cannot open file 'boost_python-vc110-mt-1_60.lib'" error

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, boost

I have set the include directory and library location in vs property to boost location but while compiling it says

> cannot open file 'boost_python-vc110-mt-1_60.lib'

From where should I get this lib? Please tell me a way compile it in vs 2013.

I have not tried bjam and not sure how it works

```
void display()
{
cout<<"Hello";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(testdll)
{
def("display", display);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the full trace? It is not so easy to diagnose without more detailed info.

Comment: Did you add `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` to `Preprocessor Definitions`? `vc110` in the library name indicates you are trying to use boost built by VS2012. If that is really the case (check what is the name of boost python dll you have in your boost lib you want to use) then did you change `Platform Toolset` to `VisualStudio 2012 (vc110)`?

Comment: I have tried adding BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK to Preprocessor Definitions and changed the toolset to v120. now the error is :Error 2 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc120-mt-1_60.lib'.
I manually searched for that library and it was not available in boost directory. Is it generated while compiling?.

Comment: I am not sure if I have to rebuild boost library or not. Please help me with the steps for clean build of boost